# How to set onchange of two dropdown in JQuery & CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, onchange, segment

I'm using CodeIgniter and I have a question in setting onchange on two dropdown using JQuery,
here is the code :

```
<?
function generateSelect($name = '', $options = array(), $code) {
    $html = '<select name="'.$name.' id="'.$name.'"">';
    foreach ($options->result_array() as $row) {
        if ($row[$name] == $code) {
        $html .= '<option value='.$row[$name].' selected>'.$row[$name].'</option>';
        } else {
        $html .= '<option value='.$row[$name].'>'.$row[$name].'</option>';
        }
    }
    $html .= '</select>';
    return $html;
}

echo '<div id="actype"><table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2 border=1><tr><td>AC TYPE</td><td>'.generateSelect('actype', $query_1, $actype).'</td>';

echo '<div id="acreg"><tr><td>AC REG</td><td>'.generateSelect('acreg', $query_2, $acreg).'</td></div></table>';
?>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
$(function() {           
// navigate to page on click event           
$('#actype').bind('change', function() { goToPage(); } );      
$('#acreg').bind('change', function() { goToPage(); } );      
});       

function goToPage() {
location.href = 'http://localhost/CAMP/CI/index.php/blog/show_package/'+$("#actype :selected").val()+'/'+$("#acreg :selected").val();
} 
</script>
```

So when the first dropdown is selected, the page will add some uri segment. 
And based on that segment, some query will run and then list of second dropdown is generated.

The problem is when the second dropdown is selected, the page adds "undefined" as new segment. I think the page cannot fetch the selected value of second dropdown.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a " missing in this line:

```
$html = '<select name="'.$name.'" id="'.$name.'"">';
```

Also would be wise to wrap the value properties, like:

```
$html .= '<option value="'.$row[$name].'">'.$row[$name].'</option>';
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that, what you think of second dropdown issues that giving "undefined" as result?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's hard to know if you're ever actually selecting an element the first time around.

```
if ($row[$name] == $code) {
    $html .= '<option value='.$row[$name].' selected>'.$row[$name].'</option>';
}
```

If you don't pass a value to $code or there isn't a match here you won't have a valid match for your jQuery ":selected" call.  Leaving you with an "undefined" value.

```
$("#actype :selected").val()
```

or

```
$("#acreg :selected").val()
```

If you do have a match and it still doesn't work try changing your default selection to selected="selected"

```
$html .= '<option value='.$row[$name].' selected="selected">'.$row[$name].'</option>';
```